# What is the best bundle in Symfony 4 for create an API?

Tags: api, symfony4

What is the best bundle in Symfony 4 for create an API?

I have planned to create a frontend with Vue.js without use Symfony.

The Symfony 4 documentation have not many pages about api the best way to create an api.

Comment: Apart from the fact that a question for “best” never makes sense if the requirements are not known, there is the `api` Flex recipe. In other words: there is an official recommendation to use http://flexrecipes.org/recipes/api-platform/api-pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's https://api-platform.com now.
With a great documentation.